# Missing or conflicting dependencies when try to start a new jetpack compose project

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, android-jetpack-compose

I want to start a new project using jet pack compose. when make the project i get this error in my `MainActivity` and the word "compose" is red in the imported libraries. It seems android studio can't access to libraries.

[image: Main activity]

this is the `build.gradle(Moudle:app)` file :

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.myapplication'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.4.3'
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.2'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.8.1'
    implementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.03.00')
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3'
    implementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.03.00')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    androidTestImplementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.03.00')
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4'
    androidTestImplementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.03.00')
    debugImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling'
    debugImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest'
}
```

I noticed there are no versions in some dependencies so i added the suggestion of android and still had the problem. I have searched a lot and didn't found anything.

I have no idea what to do. How can i fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

You have a duplicate line in your dependencies: `implementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.03.00')` and it is duplicated in the `androidTestImplementation`  dependencies too.

You can delete them and try the more recent BOM, i.e. `implementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.10.01')`.

Comment: i did and it works. all the errors gone. but i still have this error : "Cannot access class 'androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp' check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies" on the 'Surface' and 'Text'

Comment: ```kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.4.3'``` is also out of date. Needs to be changed to 1.5.4. Should not be related to your error though. Have you cleaned the project?

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. I updated android studio to latest version and the problem solved by itself.